# Detect when player attacks another player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to detect when a player attacks/hits/hurts another player or entity. I have tried to use the `AttackTime` tag, but it doesn't work. Here is what I have tried (on a 20HZ clock):

First command block:

```
scoreboard players set @a Attack 0 {AttackTime:0s}
```

Second command block:

```
scoreboard players set @a Attack 1 {AttackTime:1s}
```

Third command block:

```
tellraw @a[score_Attack_min=1] "Nice shot!"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. I use the `stat.damageDealt` scoreboard objective. First I run the following command **once**:

```
/scoreboard objectives add hit stat.damageDealt
```

Then on the **20Hz clock** I do the following:

- First command block:

  `/tellraw @a[score_hit_min=1] "Nice Hit!"`
- Second command block:

  `/scoreboard players reset @a[score_hit_min=1] hit`

How this works is that points is added to the `stat.damageDealt` objective each time they hit/attack/hurt an entity or player. Then it runs the command on every player that has hurt another entity or player. When that command is done, the objective gets reset.

How I found this is that on the statistics menu from the pause menu, there is a statistic called *Damage Dealt*.

***EDIT:***

In Minecraft 1.9, use the **repeating command block** instead of a **20Hz clock**.

Comment: I've been working on a different solution, which is much more complicated. I feel stupid now.

Comment: @MrLemon Oh, well you can post it, maybe it will be helpful to some players.

Comment: @MrLemon That is if it is done.

Comment: I ended up using something I found out while fiddling around with my solution (which was just awful to be hones) to upgrade your solution.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that `stat.damageDealt` isn't further subdivided into the various mobs and players.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on @CommandFox's answer and my own (totally awful) idea for a solution. However, I found that combination of the two adds a possible limitation to hurting specific entities.

First, create two scoreboard objectives: `didDamage` and `hurtTime`

```
scoreboard objectives add didDamage stat.damageDealt
scoreboard objectives add hurtTime dummy
```

Then, create a fill clock and run the following commands:

```
scoreboard players add @e hurtTime 1 
scoreboard players set @e hurtTime 0 {HurtTime:0s}

execute @e[score_hurtTime_min=1,score_hurtTime=1] ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a[score_didDamage=1] "Nice hit!"
scoreboard player set @a didDamage 0
```

So far, we have gained nothing by using the `hurtTime` objective. The main benefit of it is that it can be limited using its target selector. For example, using

```
scoreboard players add @e[type=Zombie] hurtTime 1 
scoreboard players set @e[type=Zombie] hurtTime 0 {HurtTime:0s}
```

makes it so that the message only appears when you actually hit a zombie. Using multiples of this command block pair makes it possible to select multiple entities.

Comment: This solution is great for when you want to limit the mobs or players that the player may hit. Thank you.

Comment: @CommandFox I'm just glad I was able to salvage something useful from my attempt after all. For players, you could also use `stat.damageTaken` instead, but `stat`-objectives do not work for other entities.

Comment: Incidentally, I found out that after hitting a mob, it is invincible (glowing red) for exactly 10 ticks (1/2 sec).

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help. I have a use for this on one of my command block minigames.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that. Thanks :D