# How to detect if a mob has been hit in minecraft with command blocks? 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok so is there any way of detecting if mob takes damage. I found this thread but it was for 1.9 
[How to detect if a mob has been hit in minecraft with command blocks?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/252661/how-to-detect-if-a-mob-has-been-hit-in-minecraft-with-command-blocks)

Comment: its just the same as in that thread? afaik that didn't change from 1.8 to 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "tagging" feature for `/scoreboard` used in the other answer was introduced in 1.9, but the process is still the same. You will instead need to use a score:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Hit dummy
```

And then on a clock, ensuring correct activation order, you would cycle the score between 1 and 0 depending on the value of the `HurtTime` tag:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Creeper] Hit 1 {HurtTime:10s}
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Creeper] Hit 0 {HurtTime:9s}
/execute @e[type=Creeper,score_Hit_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /say I am a creeper that was hit.
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have only one problem: This doesn't work when an entity dies. So in my case it doesn't do the playsound command when mob dies. Any solution for this? /execute @e[name=Ghost,score_Hit_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /playsound mob.endermen.hit @a ~ ~ ~ 0.5 1.6 (command i'm using)

Comment: Nevermind i solved it! It took like 1.5h but hey it works now ^_^