# How would I have a command block detect when a specific mob is hit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map, and I require that whenever certain animals are hit a string of events will occur. I tried looking around to see if I could synthesize some form of a working answer but it seems to be flying over my head. Essentially what I want is some form of command that will detect the player nearest to the hit mob, and then I could use chain command blocks for my additional needs. I know I need to use a chain command block, and I know this has to do something with HurtTime, but I just can't piece it all together.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! Can you supply some sample commands that you've tried unsuccessfully? They may help us piece together a working answer for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, entities have a `HurtTime` of `0s`. You can see this by using `/data get entity @s HurtTime`, using yourself as an example. When an entity is hit, its `HurtTime` gets set to `10s` and decreases every tick until it has reached `0s` again.

You can test for nbt in selectors like this:

```
execute as @e[nbt={HurtTime:10s}] at @s run particle angry_villager ~ ~2 ~
```

*(Repeating command every tick)*

---

You can tag the player nearest to the hit mob like this:

```
execute as @e[nbt={HurtTime:10s}] at @s run tag @p add closest_to_mob
```

*(Repeating command every tick)*

Comment: The commands work wonderfully, but I have another problem now. The text I have set just keeps sending in chat indefinitely. How do I remedy this so that the text is only sent once. Also, how would you set the hurt time for specific mobs?

Comment: You can tag the entity you wish to detect, and use that in the selector. Like so: `@e[tag=example,nbt={HurtTime:10s}]`. As for your repeating text issue, I don't know how you set it up and cannot help.

Comment: @Sammy don't forget to click or tap the checkbox next to this answer if it answered your question!

Comment: For the text, I attached a chain command block that doesn't require redstone to a chain command block that also doesn't require redstone with the following command you gave earlier, "execute as @e[nbt={HurtTime:10s}] at @s run tag @p add closest_to_mob". Idk if this is enough information, but I hope it is.

Comment: Nvm, I figured it all out. I combined this answer with another question on the site to create my desired effect. Here's the link to the other question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/252661/how-to-detect-if-a-mob-has-been-hit-in-minecraft-with-command-blocks If anyone wants, I can go more in depth into how I combined the two to fix my problem