# How do I force a player turn his head when i hit them?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there anyway that can force a player that I have hit to turn his head upward? I try to create something like an uppercut in 1.15.2 minecraft multiplayer server. I believe it is related to damagedealt scoreboard and hurttime detection but i dont know how to put them together though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, this should help link it up - [Detect when player attacks another player](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226755/detect-when-player-attacks-another-player)
I did the command /execute as @p run tp @p ~ ~ ~ ~ -90 to force my head upward.  Link @p with the value you're using.