# How to detect a player right-clicking with an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a "lightning rod" in Minecraft. I'll have a stick or something that when right-clicked, it summons lightning one block in front of player.

How can I detect a player right-clicking with a specific item in hand?

Comment: [Related/possible duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/226476/107806)

Comment: The answer depends on what the "something" you're right clicking with is. There are easy ways to detect placing down blocks, casting fishing rods, blocking with swords, etc.. Harder to detect if you're using a blaze rod or item that doesn't already do something special with right clicked, but still possible.

Comment: I want to use a stick, but now that you say it, a sword would be great!

Comment: @CollinFitch Also, does this need to work in 1.8.8 or are you using the snapshots? (Makes a difference, but not a huge one)

Comment: /testfor isn't for events, it detects entity presence.

Comment: So do you want to make a lightning rod or detect the player?

Answer (score 0):

Well..you could use a fishing rod,and test for the entity when you right click the rod.
The fishing rod bobber is an entity which gets summoned when you right click the fishing rod. The bobber's entity name is "unknown". So just /testfor @e[type=Unknown]
 Normal items can't be tested for right click because they don't do anything. The only way to do it,it's to do it with plugins

Comment: How exactly can s/he "use a fishing rod,and test for the entity when you right click the rod"?

Comment: Well,the fishing rod bobber is an entity which gets summoned when you right click the fishing rod. The bobber's entity name is "unknown". So just /testfor @e[type=Unknown]

Comment: adding that to the answer can be a better choice