# Create a Minecraft Item that Executes a Command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using creative mode to tag Minecraft villagers as an adult or child.

Here is the code I am using: 
`/data merge entity @e[type=villager,limit=1,sort=nearest] {Tags:["child"]}` 
`/data merge entity @e[type=villager,limit=1,sort=nearest] {Tags:["adult"]}`

However, I want players in survival mode to be able to add these data tags to villagers. Can I create an item that, when right clicked, will execute one of these commands? I think I may need to use a carrot on a stick (since it can detect a right click) but I am not certain. Ideally, I would like to use two sticks: one called "child age wand" and the other called "adult age wand." How would I do this?

Comment: Do you want this to tag the closest villager (easy, just use useItem scoreboard for carrot on a stick and select closest villager) or the one that the player is looking at (very complicated and laggy, requires raytracing)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply an effect when a player left-clicks/right-clicks with an item in hand?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226476/how-can-i-apply-an-effect-when-a-player-left-clicks-right-clicks-with-an-item-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only item which supports right-click detection without using tricky methods is the carrot on a stick so that's what I will use for this example.

First, you need an objective to track when the player right-clicks with it. This only needs to be initialized once so you can run it in chat.

```
/scoreboard objectives add clicked minecraft.used:minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick
```

this command needs to run in a repeating command block:

```
/execute at @a[scores={clicked=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick",tag:{display:{Name:"\"name_here\""}}}}] run tag @e[type=villager,limit=1,sort=nearest] add child
```

^ write one more for the other carrot on a stick but change the name and tag. This command should be running in a chain (always active) command block attached to the repeating one:

```
/scoreboard players reset @a[scores={clicked=1..}] clicked
```

to generate your carrots on a stick, use this command:

```
/give @s minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick{display:{Name:"\"name_here\""}}
```