# How to detect a player's left-click

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm writing a command for a customised enchantment that teleports a player holding a certain item to the direction that it's facing. However, according to my knowledge, there's no statistic in `/scoreboard` that could simply detect a player's left-click.

The scores that I've though about include `damage_dealt` that detects whether a player causes damage. However, I don't actually need the player to cause damage to activate the teleporting, so this may not work because the player can click without causing damage also thought about the `ITEM_USE` score, but this does not include left-click either, only right click.

Anyone could tell me how to detect the player's left-click please? Thank you!

Comment: Hello! In what way are you writing the command? Is this for a plugin written in Java?

Comment: Well, it is in-game command for command block

Comment: Do you want to detect when a user uses a specific item or just any item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I apply an effect when a player left-clicks/right-clicks with an item in hand?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226476/how-can-i-apply-an-effect-when-a-player-left-clicks-right-clicks-with-an-item-in)

Comment: It looks like you really can't, see the duplicate

Comment: That answer does not help in fact. It was more likely to be a workaround but does not really tell me what the scoreboard for left-click is